# React native create Textfield with predefined format of dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have created my own Texfield which I use throughout my app. I would now like to create a Textfield which has a predefined format of the input. So for example as seen below in the image I want the text to always have the format `dd/mm/yyyy` and that the input jumps to the month when the date is filled in.

This image is an example of what I try to accomplish:

[image]

This is my custom Textfield which is basically the native `TextInput` with some styling.

[image]

```js
//Input.tsx
interface Props {
  errorMessage?: string
  placeholder: string
  value: string
  onChange: (text: string) => void
}

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({
  errorMessage,
  placeholder,
  onChange,
  value,
}) => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Box marginVertical="xs">
      <Box
        borderColor={errorMessage ? 'error' : focused ? 'primary' : 'inputBG'}
        paddingVertical="inputS"
        paddingHorizontal="inputM"
        borderRadius="s"
        borderWidth={2}
        backgroundColor={errorMessage ? 'inputErrorBG' : 'inputBG'}
      >
        <TextInput
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
          onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          value={value}
        />
      </Box>
      {errorMessage ? <Text color="error">{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mask-input) which provides the component `MaskInput` which makes it possible to define masks to format the input.

Below I extended my custom `Input` with the `variant` props to display the MaskInput when the variant is "date".

```
import MaskInput, { Masks } from 'react-native-mask-input'

{variant === 'date' ? (
  // @ts-ignore
  <MaskInput
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    mask={Masks.DATE_DDMMYYYY}
    onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
    onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
    onChangeText={(formatted) => onChange(formatted)}
    value={value}
    keyboardType={keyboardType}
  />
) : (
  <TextInput
    placeholder={placeholder}
    onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
    onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
    onChangeText={onChange}
    value={value}
    keyboardType={keyboardType}
  />
)}
```